# VUEX getters returned too fast

Tags: vue.js

I've a problem with getters. At first I call an action `getWeather` which is `async`:

```
export const actions = {
        async getWeather ({commit, state}) {
        try {
            const locationResponse = await VueGeolocation.getLocation({ enableHighAccuracy: true });
            const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${locationResponse.lat}&lon=${locationResponse.lng}&units=metric&appid=${process.env.apikey}`;

            const response = await fetch(url);
            const data = await response.json();
            await commit('SET_WEATHER', data);
            console.log(`DATA: ${data}`) // returns me the weather data

        } catch (error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
    }
}
```

and then in my `index.vue` file I make this:

```
<script>
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default {
  beforeCreate() {
    this.$store.dispatch('getWeather');
  },
  created() {
    console.log(this.$store.getters.getWeatherInfo) // returns null
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['getWeatherInfo'])
  }
}
</script>
```

This returns me the `null` value from the state even though I `mutate` the state.
`created() { console.log(this.$store.getters.getWeatherInfo) // returns null`

Vuex mutation:

```
export const mutations = {
    SET_WEATHER (state, payload) {
        state.weather = payload;
    }
}
```

How do I get the weather data then not null in the `index.vue` file ?

Comment: Do you really need `getWeatherInfo` to have value in `created` or is it just an "experiment" ?

Comment: Not necessary, it also doesn't work with the computed getter

Comment: `await commit('SET_WEATHER', data);` - remove `await`, commit is synchronous (doesn't return Promis) and cannot be awaited...

Comment: It's still `null`, and in the console I can see that at first I get getters value `null` then the `console.log(`DATA: ${data}`)` logs me weather object

Comment: Of course, because in `created` your asynchronous calls (from action) are not completed yet

Comment: Okay I've added `async/await` on `created` hook and removed `beforeCreate` hook and I get the data now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you see `null` in `created` is because asynchronous action started in `beforeCreate` is not complete yet.

If you really need result of the action to be complete in created you need to to this:

```js
async created() {
  await this.$store.dispatch('getWeather');
  console.log(this.$store.getters.getWeatherInfo) // now the data is in store
}
```

If you don't need data to be ready in `created` it's better to remove `await` and write your component template using `v-if` - "render this only if my getter is not null" ...it will be not-null eventually ("sometime in the future") and Vue will re-render your component...